# batch file wont properly read lines

Tags: batch-file

testread.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f %%i in (test.txt) do (
  set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
  set /a Counter+=1
)

set /a NumLines=Counter - 1
echo %Line_1%
echo %Line_2%
echo %Line_3%
echo %Line_4%
echo %Line_5%
echo %Line_6%
pause
```

test.txt

> line 1
>
> line 2
>
> line 3
>
> line - 4
>
> (this line is to purposely try to trip up the reader. just a test)
>
> line 5 -^#^@&
>
> line 6
>
> line 7

output

> line
>
> line
>
> line
>
> line
>
> line
>
> line
>
> press enter to continue (something like that)

how would i fix it so the output reads the whole line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (test.txt) do (
```

see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation

Comment: would you be able to help. theres alot of code packed into for and itd take awhile for me to find out what happened

Comment: also i had %%i before but somehow it only gave line also. must've been my formatting. thanks for helping.